# How to send SCSI Mode Select command with Caching Mode Page (08h) to disable CD-ROM caching?

Tags: c++, caching, scsi, cd-rom

For some purposes I want CD-ROM drive always read sectors from medium (disc) not retrieve them from cache (volatile or non-volatile).
I know I should use Caching Mode Page (08h). Sending other SCSI command such as 28h (READ CD) or BBh (SET CD SPEED) was fine and easy but I have no idea how to send Mode Select with caching mode page option or structure, I don't know exactly.

I've searched this so much but found nothing. So please give me a detailed C++ code to disable CD-ROM caching or some code to read sectors from medium.

Thanks

Comment: Clearly you know how to send SCSI commands. Did you read the official **Mode Select 08h** spec yet? See [SBC-3](ftp://ftp.t10.org/t10/document.05/05-369r0.pdf) section 6.3.4, for instance.

Comment: Right I know how to send SCSI commands but up to now all of the commands I sent just need Cdb array to fill. My exact question is how I should add cache mode page parameters? and Is there any way to read sectors from medium except using caching mode page?